# How to share libraries across many files python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, python-module

I checked few similiar questions and couldn't find satisfying answer. What is good practice if you want to reuse libraries across many different files. This is what I do right now:

```
# LIB.py
import sys
import platform
import socket

import mypyfile1
import mypyfile2


# RANDOM_PYFILE.py
import LIB

LIB.library.some_function()
```

Is this correct way to deal with this problem or is there better way?

Comment: No, it's not a great idea just to dump all of your common libraries in 1 module and then import that. I don't know what problem this is solving, but now every project has a single dependency that you now have to include with it should you try tun on another computer/instance etc

Comment: In fact, quite the opposite, the general practice is to have a _virtual environment_ that is specific to each project. Libraries deprecate methods and add new ones all the time, so you'll then end up with a central import that cannot support two or more projects because there is an API mismatch

Comment: That sounds like a good way to build yourself into a situation where you're forced to update your API/module tho. I like the sound of people updating their stuff.

Comment: Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is not like JavaScript where importing a script multiple times will cause multiple executions.

Nor is it like C or CSS where importing/including a file multiple times will cause that file to be defined multiple times in your code. Python is smart enough to only import something once if it needs to.

So go ahead and import everything you need in all the files that need it as many times as you want. Python will only ever load it in the process once.

In fact this has created a specific issue with file reloading in Python where simply reimporting a file doesn't update your code. Python has a solution for this in the [reload](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reload) function. But you don't need that obviously.

So don't worry. Import as many times as you want. That *is* the best practice in Python.

Comment: That would explain why this problem isn't talked about more as it seems simplest solution is the best one.

Comment: The simplest solution being the best one is a core tenet of pythons philosophy :-).